# Connection SAP and Android through JCo

Tags: android, eclipse, connection, jco

I try to connect ANDROID with SAP system via RFC... Is that possible ?
I think its possible because [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJSkqS-dxkw) shows de connection but I don't know why JCo version (he uses strange classes)

I am working on Windows 7 (x86) and Eclipse IDE.

I have added `sapjco.jar` to the library project,

added these files to SYSTEM32 FOLDER( `sapjcorfc.dll`, `librfc32.dll` )

That´s my code:

```java
package com.example.jco32;

import android.app.Activity;
import com.sap.mw.jco.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    
      JCO.Client client = null;
      JCO.Function funcion = null;
      JCO.Table t_spfli = null;

      IRepository repositorio = null;
      IFunctionTemplate ftemplate = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ejecutarjco();
                    }
                
                });    
        
    }
    
   

> public void ejecutarjco() {

>      System.out.println("i entered to hte method");

       
       try {
           client = JCO.createClient("100",
                                     "USER",
                                     "PASS",
                                     "EN",
                                     "/H/111.22.52.198/W/TESTING/H/172.25.10.21",
                                     "02");
         
         //abre la conexion
           System.out.print("BEFORE CONNECT()");
            client.connect();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.print("connected");
            
       
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Error:" +e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I got the next error (all lines below are actually prefixed `09-26 02:03:48.934: E/AndroidRuntime(670):`, e.g. the first line `FATAL EXCEPTION: main` is actually `09-26 02:03:48.934: E/AndroidRuntime(670): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`):

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     at com.example.jco32.MainActivity.ejecutarjco(MainActivity.java:46)
>     at com.example.jco32.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCO.classInitialize():  Could not
>     load middleware layer 'com.sap.mw.jco.rfc.MiddlewareRFC'
> null
>     at com.sap.mw.jco.JCO.<clinit>(JCO.java:776)
>   ... 13 more
> ```

I hope your help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. JCo requires a native library that is not available for Android platforms.

Comment: I Thought the same as you, but there is a video which shows a connection with JCO
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJSkqS-dxkw
Regards

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read the title - "JCo like".

Comment: ohhhh..
Thanks for your comments.
Unfortunately i had to think in another alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write some REST/SOAP webService which connects via JCo to SAP and then you just have to send standard HTTP request to your WS, there you fetch data from SAP and return it to Android as JSON/XML response.